# Regular expression for matching like given words

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to put together a regular expression for matching multiple words.
I have an import file the has a column header that will be something like *"item description"* since there will be multiple headers it can't get too greedy on what matches. For example *"item location description"* should not match when looking for *"item description"* it will have its own matching regex.

I have put together the following: `(?i)(?<=^|\s)Item Description(?=\s|$)` but it does not quite work for all cases.

**Some Valid Cases (ignore case):**

- item description
- item_description
- some junk before the words item description
- item description some junk after the words

**Some Not Valid Cases (ignore case):**

- Item Location Description
- Location Description
- media item
- type description
- item
- Description

Comment: Note that the lookaround are useless here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily test your Regex on RegexStorm website.

For your purpose, if the only case that doesn't fit is the one with "_", just add it to your pattern :

```
(?i)(?<=^|\s)Item[ \t_]Description(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: This will also take "Item\nDescription" which is invalid according to the OP.

Comment: This works pretty well. Is there a way to make it match on an optional prefix of Records? So item description and records item description would both be valid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(?i)item[ _]description
```